# Redirecting to the devise controller after successfull login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, devise

I am new in Ruby On Rails. I am making an application using devise gem. My requirement is after logged in successfully I should redirect to devise controller again.

I have created devise controller as 'Users'

I have created one more controller `home_controller.rb` for redirecting
under `home` controller I have coded this.

```
def index
  if user_signed_in?
    redirect_to :controller => 'users', :action =>add
  end
end
```

I have written `add` method under `users_controller.rb`

And under `routes.rb` I have coded this

```
devise_for :users, controllers:{sessions: "users/sessions"}
root :to => 'home#index'
match 'users/:action' => 'users#add', :as => :add
```

But its not redirecting. What should I do. any help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get "add"
  end
end
```

Comment: `undefined method 'add_url' for #<HomeController:0xab0c73c>` --- This error is coming

Comment: under `rake routes` also add function is not available

Comment: this error is coming ----`uninitialized constant users`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you'll want to use the [Devise redirect helpers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-and-sign-out):

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      user_add_path
   end
end
```

---

I don't understand is this:

> I should redirect to devise controller again

[**Devise controllers**](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/app/controllers/devise) are split into `SessionsController`, `RegistrationsController`, `PasswordsController`, `ConfirmationsController` & `UnlocksController`.

Which one would you like to redirect to?

My hunch, and this is strengthened after reading your comments, is you want to redirect to the `UsersController`, like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users, only: :show do
   get :add
end

#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def add
      //declarations here
   end

   def show
      //declarations here
   end
end
```

This should help you

Comment: `User`  is devise controller .. I want to redirect to it after logged in successfully. I have one more controller `home`(here I am checking whether it is signed in successfully or not). I have to redirect to `UsersController` from `HomeController`

Comment: Okay, you need to be careful what you call a "devise controller". If you read my answer & provided documentation, you'll see that `users_controller` is not part of the Devise structure. Devise uses its own controllers. The `User` *model* is a Devise model, but the controllers don't have any such bind to Devise. If you read my answer carefully, you'll see exactly what you need

Comment: I have triedd it under `ApplicationController` but getting the same error

Comment: i have created devise controller using `rails g devise:controller Users`

Comment: Tried what under applicationcontroller?

Comment: Okay, back to fundamentals -- does your Devise installation currently work (let's you register & login)?

Comment: Ya ya.. it is working properly. Then I have created one `UserController`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52647/discussion-between-rich-peck-and-d-scolz)